# Getting a Paper Published

Tags: academic-graduate, institutions

I have a nice and (I think) significant result. I would like to publish it, but I have no idea how. It's a proof of an optimal institutional structure. Who do I contact?

Comment: Are you a student? Undergrad/grad? Do you know anyone in the field? Without some context, there is little concrete advice anyone could give you.

Comment: I think you'd get more helpful responses if you asked on Academia Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your paper is rigorous enough, you might want to submit it to a peer-reviewed specialized journal. Journals pertaining to Economics are the [Quarterly Journal of Economics](https://academic.oup.com/qje), [Journal of Macroeconomics](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/journal-of-macroeconomics), [The Economic Journal](http://www.res.org.uk/view/economichome.html), and many others. Many of these journals have a link for writers to submit their paper and a "guide for authors". Likewise, search on Google for *Call For Papers*.

The question by @MichaelGreinecker (whether *you know anyone in the field*) makes me wonder whether being accepted for publication also depends on having connections with the editorial, rather than being exclusively a matter of rigor of the research.

Comment: No, being accepted for publication does not depend on having connections with the editorial; it's that if bEPIK knew people in the field, they could ask them to work out whether it is publishable or not, and if so, to mentor them through the process of writing it up as a paper, and/or co-author with them.

Comment: Exactly what @EnergyNumbers wrote.

Comment: Just to add my 1 cent: In statistics, and I'm confident that it's true for economics also, the journal that you submit to is often the deciding factor for whether it is accepted. An applied statistics paper is not going to be accepted by annals of statistics or biometrika and a theoretical paper is not going to be accepted by technometrics or quality control. So, you need to get your paper categorized  by yourself or someone who has experience in publishing before you submit. The process can be quite difficult so expect a wild ride in terms of revisions then re-submissions etc. good luck.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers: "being accepted for publication does not depend on having connections with the editorial". That is the noble ideal but unfortunately not one that is always achieved. Connections and cronyism crop up in every walk of life, including academic economics.

Comment: Another important factor that "shouldn't" matter but unfortunately does is your reputation. A work of genius that comes out of nowhere is less likely to be published than a piece of junk by a Nobel laureate. (One well-known example is Akerlof's lemons paper, submitted when Akerlof was a "nobody", first rejected by the AER for being "trivial", then rejected by the JPE for being "wrong". This problem is probably more severe today than in the 1960s.)

Comment: @KennyLJ much *less* severe today than in the 1960s, because there are just so many more journals now, And yes, connections are helpful, but publication does not *depend* on them: connections are helpful, but are neither necessary nor sufficient.

Comment: Whether or not nepotism is a problem in the field is not really the point here.

We need to establish if OP has the writing experience and familiarity with appropriate norms for writing in the field. Is his/her writing clear? Is his/her research persuasive and unambiguous? Does it follow standard formatting conventions?   These will take you 99% of the way to publication in nearly any journal.